# How to change url of two pages in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-services, url

I want to change URL in htaccess

```
/grid.php?view=Samsung

/mobile.php?id=Galaxy-j5
```

to

```
/Samsung 

/Samsung/Galaxy-j5
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty basic

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) mobile.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) grid.php?view=$1 [L]
```